# How to design this overlapped in css

Tags: html, css

[image]
Is there any way to create overlapped design like the below image using CSS and html

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 4):

You can use `position: relative;` and move the second `div` using `top: -30px;` (or whatever value you need).

```css
.div-1 {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px 20px 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.div-2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: -30px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">Div 1</div>
<div class="div-2">Div 2</div>
```

Comment: better to use `margin-top: -30px` instead of `position: relative; top: -30px;` (to avoid blank space under red element).

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative margins.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.div-1,
.div-2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.div-1 {
    height: 125px;
    background: blue;
}

.div-2 {
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="div-1">
        <h1> Div 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="div-2">
        <h1> Div 2</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this by positioning the elements absolute to parent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.parent{
position:relative;
}
.child1{
position:absolute;
top:0;
height:100px;
background:red;
width:100%;
}
.child2{
position:absolute;
top:40px;
left:5%;
height:100px;
background:blue;
width:90%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
<div class="child1">
div1
</div>
<div class="child2">
div2
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this type of positioning, we don't need positioning attributes.

```css
.box1{
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 60px;
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
}
.box2{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 60px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: -50px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
<p>box1</p>
</div>
<div class="box2">
<p>overlap box</p>
</div>
```